# Mostrar datos array bidimensional. Java

Tags: java, array-bidimensional

Me gustaría mostrar los datos del `array`. He creado una **clase Nota** que reciben dos `int` y un `string` y la utilizo para construir un `arreglo bidimensional` en el que inserto una nota en cada celda.

Me gustaría imprimir el array pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Por otra parte, como es un `array` de objetos y cada uno tiene 3 datos, ¿de que manera puedo acceder a cada uno de los datos que alberga cada objeto?

**Clase Nota:**

```
package ejemplo;

public class Nota{
    private String seller;
    private int numero_producto;
    private int valor_producto;


    public Nota (String s, int p,  int v) {
        seller=s;
        numero_producto=p;
        valor_producto=v;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Vendedor" + seller+ "\t"+numero_producto +"\t"+ valor_producto;
    }
}
```

**Clase Dia:**

```
package ejemplo;

import java.util.Random;

public class Dia{
    private Nota[][]dia;
    private static final Random random = new Random(); 

    public Dia(){
        String[]vendedor = {"Juan", "Mike", "Pepe", "Nino"};
        int[]producto = {99, 119, 89, 39, 79};

        dia = new Nota[5][4];
        for(int i=0; i<dia.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<dia[i].length; j++) {
                dia[i][j] = new Nota(vendedor[j%4], producto[i%5], producto[i%5]*random.nextInt(5));                                                          
            }
        }
    }

    public void getDatos(Dia[][]array) {
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++) { 
                System.out.println(array[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

**Clase Ventas:**

```
package ejemplo;
import ejemplo.Dia;

import java.util.Random;

public class Ventas{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dia data = new Dia();
        data.getDatos();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a esta comunidad. Lo primero te recomiendo que mires otras preguntas para saber cómo agregar el código y poner una explicación clara del problema con separaciones, comas, puntos, etc. El enunciado está todo alborotado, y también, es aconsejabe que pongas sangrías en el código para que sea mas legible. Gracias.

Comment: @omaza1990 gracias. Así lo haré. A ver si aprendo a hacer sangrías aquí, que el tabulador en el editor me salta a otro campo de la página

Comment: Con que tengas bien tabulado tu código en tu IDE es suficiente. Añade el código aquí haciendo un copy-paste y dando al símbolo {} y automáticamente te acepta la sangría.

Comment: Mira la edición que te ofrecí del enunciado y mira qué diferencia y organización respecto a la inicial. ;)

Comment: @omaza1990 ciertamente la diferencia es más que notable y teniendo en cuenta que lo que se escribe es código, entiendo perfectamente que sea más que aconsejable escribir de forma clara y concisa. Me proponía eliminar la pregunta formulada e intentarlo de nuevo rehaciéndola

Comment: .. y gracias por la edición. De ahora en adelante formularé las preguntas de esta forma que invitan mucho más a  formular una respuesta. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estabas imprimiendo las instancias del objeto Nota, a parte de que no le tendrías que pasar parámetros a la función ya que tienes la lista en los atributos del objeto, prueba así:

```
public void getDatos() {
        for(int i=0; i<this.dia.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<this.dia[i].length; j++) { 
                System.out.println(this.dia[i][j].toString());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Esto funciona jeje. Mil gracias. Voy a estudiar como y porqué. Mil gracias

Comment: @Javi El motivo del porque no te funciona tu código es porque no le pasaste el argumento adecuado al método `getDatos`.

Comment: @MrDave1999 gracias, estoy en ello. Aún ando encajando piezas con la respuesta que me ha dado Gonzalo-GC, que funciona e intento terminar el ejercicio. No obstante, en cuanto tome cuerpo, voy a implementar lo que has apuntado, que quiero combinar con un enum todo esto. Mil Gracias. Es increíble lo  que ando avanzando ahora gracias a vuestras respuestas respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos problemas en tu código:

**1.** En ningún momento le pasas un argumento al parámetro del método `getDatos`.

**2.** El tipo de parámetro que le has puesto al método `getDatos` no es el correcto:

```java
public void getDatos(Dia[][]array)
```

El tipo `Dia[][]` indica que el parámetro debe recibir una matriz de objetos de tipo `Dia`, sin embargo, hacer esto no tiene mucho sentido, porque el objetivo de tu código es imprimir los datos de la matriz `Nota[][]`.

Entonces debemos cambiar el encabezado del método a:

```java
public void getDatos(Nota[][] array)
```

Ahora necesitamos crear un `getter` (en realidad es un método) para poder acceder al contenido de la variable `dia` (porque es privada).

El getter debe estar definido en la clase `Dia` de esta forma:

```java
public Nota[][] getNotas()
{
    return dia;
}
```

Por último, después de instanciar la clase `Dia`, debes invocar el getter y pasar el objeto al parámetro del método `getDatos`, de este modo, podremos imprimir los datos de la matriz.

```java
public class Ventas{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dia data = new Dia();
        data.getDatos(data.getNotas());
    } 
}
```

*Básicamente esto es lo que intentaste hacer, solo que faltó pasar el argumento correcto.*

Otra  **solución** es quitar el parámetro que tenga el método `getDatos` y esto se debe porque la clase `Dia` declara la variable `dia` como global, por lo tanto, la podemos usar en cualquier método y de este modo evitamos invocar a `getNotas()`.

```java
public void getDatos() 
{
    for(int i=0; i<dia.length; i++)
    {
         for(int j=0; j<dia[0].length; j++) 
             System.out.println(dia[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Este código simplemente invocará implícitamente al método `toString` de la clase `Nota` e imprimirá la información del objeto.

> > ¿de que manera puedo acceder a cada uno de los datos que alberga cada objeto?

Esto da acceso a la dirección base (la del primer elemento) de X objeto (de tipo `Nota`):

```java
System.out.println(array[i][j]);
```

Donde el código de arriba el compilador lo convierte a:

```java
System.out.println(array[i][j].toString());
```

Entonces si quieres acceder al contenido de cualquier atributo de la clase `Nota`, debes crear algún `getter` que lo permita y de este modo, podrás acceder a su contenido.

**Ejemplo:**

```java
//El método getValorProducto debe estar definido en la clase Nota.
System.out.println(array[i][j].getValorProducto());
```

Comment: Por favor, rectifica tu respuesta: No puedes responder con "data.getDatos(data.getNotas());" no tiene sentido, data ya tiene en su clase notas, no necesitas pasarselo con getter. Mira mi respuesta y si la quieres explicar más en la tuya adelante pero contesta intentando hacer buenas prácticas

Comment: @Gonzalo-GC En mi respuesta trate de explicar cual era el problema con el código que estaba intentando hacer el OP. En fin, editaré la respuesta añadiendo otra solución.